# override theme function in facetapi module

Tags: search, theming

I am trying to change the markup of links created by the facetapi module.  The theme function is here

```
function theme_facetapi_link_inactive($variables) {
  $accessible_vars = array(
    'text' => $variables['text'],
    'active' => FALSE,
  );
  $accessible_markup = theme('facetapi_accessible_markup', $accessible_vars);
  $sanitize = empty($variables['options']['html']);
  $variables['text'] = ($sanitize) ? check_plain($variables['text']) : $variables['text'];
  if (isset($variables['count'])) {
    $variables['text'] .= ' ' . theme('facetapi_count', $variables);
  }
  $variables['text'] .= $accessible_markup;
  $variables['options']['html'] = TRUE;
  return theme_link($variables);
}
```

I am trying to override this function so I can change the markup without editing the module files.  I've tried MYTHEME_preprocess_facetapi_link_inactive and using a custom module but both times I can print the variables and they are correct but the links are still displayed wrong.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_facetapi_link_inactive($variables) {
  $accessible_vars = array(
    'text' => $variables['text'],
    'active' => FALSE,
  );
  $accessible_markup = theme('facetapi_accessible_markup', $accessible_vars);
  $sanitize = empty($variables['options']['html']);
  $variables['text'] = ($sanitize) ? check_plain($variables['text']) : $variables['text'];
  if (isset($variables['count'])) {
    $variables['text'] .= ' <strong>' . theme('facetapi_count', $variables) . '!!!</strong>';
  }
  $variables['text'] .= $accessible_markup;
  $variables['options']['html'] = TRUE;
  return theme_link($variables);
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, but a preprocess function doesn't look applicable to what you're trying to do. A preprocess function is used to set up variables for a theme function, not to actually produce the markup.

What it looks like you're trying to do is to override `theme_facetapi_link_inactive()` completely, in which case you don't use a preprocess function, but instead you call the function `MYTHEME_theme_function_name()` and the theme engine will use that instead of the original function.

So all you need to is change the name of your function like so:

```
function MYTHEME_facetapi_link_inactive($variables) {
  // Same code as in your example
}
```

After you clear the caches Drupal will start using that function in place of `theme_facetapi_link_inactive()` whenever it's called.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had attempted that function but I hadn't cleared the cache between changing it from preprocess.  That was just what I needed.  Thank you!